# Netbeans opens files htaccess and gitignore as markdown

Tags: php, .htaccess, netbeans, markdown

Netbeans no longer supports my .htaccess and .gitignore files. They open them as markdown files. I have therefore neither the good completion nor the coloring which is well.

I use netbeans **8.2 fr php**, I have the plugins https://github.com/madflow/flow-netbeans-markdown **v. 2.3.1**.
If I disable this plugin, the normal behavior returns. I tried to uninstall and reset the plugin. It does not work.

I use a lot of files with mardown notes. Is there another equivalent plugin? Or how to find the coloring for apache files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I reinstalled NetBeans but had to clear the configuration in the user folder before.